# Where to find which types are supported between Anorm and JDBC?

Tags: scala, anorm, playframework-2.3

Where are describe Anorm/JDBC mapping? On one side for parameter values passed to queries, on other side for columns from result sets to be parsed.

Comment: Tables describing currently supported types, and convertions, are visible in pending Anorm doc at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/documentation/manual/scalaGuide/main/sql/ScalaAnorm.md#jdbc-mappings .

Comment: It's really a pain if you want to insert into an table with more than 10 fields use anorm. Codes will go wild.

Comment: You may want to look at string interpolation support of latest Anorm release (with Play 2.3) which improve performance and can reduce verbosity to minimal, but that's not the point of this question.

Comment: I know the point here is to answer your own question, but you should do so with an actual answer with the table and highlights typed out, and not just a link. Otherwise someone is likely to delete it.

Comment: Good link is better than duplicate content that will get obselete.

Comment: The link in the top comment here is dead.

Comment: Anorm is now on is own repo: https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/master/docs/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/sql/ScalaAnorm.md#jdbc-mappings